# php converting string to time issue in year

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

I am trying to convert string to time `strtotime` operation in php

Here's my code

`echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('2 January, 2017'));`

When i do conversion for `2 January, 2016` it results as `2016-01-02`

But When i do conversion for `2 January, 2017` it results as `2016-01-02` which is expected as `2017-01-02`

What is the issue in the code and how can i fix this ? Help pls

Comment: I don't have exact reason but that comma after January is restricting the conversion and strtotime is not able to convert 2 January, 2017 properly.

Remove that , and try you will get proper date. Will update if I get the reason why its breaking with comma

Comment: Date with comma like you've specified won't work with `strtotime` function. Whatever the year you specify there with the comma syntax like that, it only returns the current year date since it's not a supported format. Try specifying like `2 January 2017` or if you're supposed to use the comma-with syntax, you could follow @Federkun answer. That's the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DateTime::createFromFormat` instead:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d F, Y', '2 January, 2017');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

`strtotime` can't read `2 January, 2017`. `2 January, 2016` produce the correct result just because is the current year. In this case `2 January, 2016` === `2 January`.